# X is not applicable for the arguments Y, when X extends Y

Tags: java

**EventHandler.java:**

```
public abstract class EventHandler<E> {
    public abstract void HandleEvent(Object sender, E e);
}
```

**Foo.java:**

```
private OnProgressEventHandler m_OnProgressEventHandler = new OnProgressEventHandler();
private class OnProgressEventHandler extends EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> {
    public void HandleEvent(Object sender, ProgressEventArgs args) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

**ProgressEventArgs.java:**

```
public class ProgressEventArgs extends EventArgs {
    /*...*/
}
```

**Bar.java:**

```
public void addProgressEventListener(EventHandler<EventArgs> listener) {
    m_OnProgress.addListener(listener);
}
```

This line:

```
myBarObject.addProgressEventListener(m_OnProgressEventHandler);
```

causes:

> The method addProgressEventListener(EventHandler) in the
>   type Bar is not applicable for the arguments (Foo.OnProgressEventHandler)

I don't understand why it doesn't compile because `OnProgressEventHandler` extends `EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs>`. I'm sure it's something trivial I missing, but I cant figure why.

Comment: Where is the m_OnProgress created and what type is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public void addProgressEventListener(EventHandler<EventArgs> listener) {
    m_OnProgress.addListener(listener);
}
```

to

```
public void addProgressEventListener(EventHandler<? extends EventArgs> listener) {
    m_OnProgress.addListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: thanks this works, now I have some other problem related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136782/java-generics-method-x-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments