# Java Generics: Method X is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java

**EventHandler.java:**

```
public abstract class EventHandler<E extends EventArgs> { 
    public abstract void HandleEvent(Object sender, E e);
}
```

**Observers.java:**

```
public class Observers<E extends EventArgs> {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? extends E>> mListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? extends E>>();

    public void dispatchEvent(Object sender, E args) {
        if (mListeners != null) {
            for (EventHandler<? extends E> listener : mListeners) {
                listener.HandleEvent(sender, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following line:

```
listener.HandleEvent(sender, args);
```

Causes:

> The method HandleEvent(Object, capture#3-of ? extends E) in the type
>   EventHandler is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Object, E)

Does anybody how to fix this?

**EDIT1**
The reason `? super E` doesn't work for me is that I have the following method inside `Observers` class:

```
public void addListener(EventHandler<? super E> listener) {
mListeners.add(listener);
}
```

And that causes:

> The method add(EventHandler) in the type
>   CopyOnWriteArrayList> is not applicable for the
>   arguments (EventHandler)

**EDIT2**

The reason the change from `? super E` to `E` doesn't work for me because of this:
[X is not applicable for the arguments Y, when X extends Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136302/x-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments-y-when-x-extends-y)

It was already like that but that didn't work neither :(

Comment: What is the type of `args`? Please post a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: It's a compile time error. It just doesn't compile

Comment: per **Edit`** Change the `private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? extends E>>` to `private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? super E>>`

Comment: per `Edit2`, yeah but your Observer class only has an `E`, if your listener is expecting a subclass of `E`, passing an `E` to it will not work because `E` might be a `G` instead of an `F`

Comment: seems like all your listeners should implement `EventHandler<E>` and do the `instanceof` and cast as appropriate.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to do mapping and filtering at the Observer level if you want to be able to handle multiple event types but want listeners to only get notified of certain event types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you declaring `mListeners` to be ~ `? extends E` rather than just `E`?

If you use

```
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<E>> mListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<E>>();
```

It'll work.

Or adopt PECS (Producer Extends, Consumer Super). As others have suggested

```
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? super E>> mListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? super E>>();
```

with related changes to the `for` loop.

Edit: A fuller example. This shows no warnings or errors, and, based on what you've given, would work.

```
public static class Sandbox {
    public static interface EventArgs {}
    public static abstract class EventHandler<E extends EventArgs> { 
        public abstract void HandleEvent(Object sender, E e);
    }
    public static class Observers<E extends EventArgs> {

        private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? super E>> mListeners
                = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<? super E>>();

        public void dispatchEvent(Object sender, E args) {
            if (mListeners != null) {
                for (EventHandler<? super E> listener : mListeners) {
                    listener.HandleEvent(sender, args);
                }
            }
        }
        public void addListener(EventHandler<? super E> listener) {
            mListeners.add(listener);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS, updated. I think you just need to maintain consistency between how you're wildcarding. It's actually not clear from your examples what you're trying to achieve. The provided answer merely does what you ask, but may not be right for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for update but now I get the error I mention here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136302/x-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments-y-when-x-extends-y

Comment: I want to create a listener interface to C#. I want all my observers to impelement the abstract `EventHandler` class and only accept arguments which subclasses of `EventArgs` class.

Comment: Ah, well this is an example of the problem being unclear. When you provide half a story in the question, people can but provide half a story in the answer. You also shouldn't split what is clearly one problem into multiple questions, it's somewhat difficult now to work out what's going on. I'll try to merge and update.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS, you're going to have to update the question with a complete set of classes. There's not enough info to determine what you have. Please simply include a single class, use static inner classes instead of a multitude of class files, like Sandbox above. Makes it much easier to copy/paste into an IDE and see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Use `? super E` instead of `? extends E`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (EventHandler<? extends E> listener : mListeners) {
```

to

```
for (EventHandler<? super E> listener : mListeners) {
```

The reason this change is required is that the class has an instance of `E`. However, if you have a listener that expects a sub-class of `E`, `E` is not guaranteed to satisfy this contract. However, if the listener expects a base-class of `E`, then `E` is guaranteed to satisfy the contract.

Comment: Change the declaration of the collection to match

Comment: I cannot `add` is a library method(defined in `CopyOnWriteArrayList`)

Comment: See my comment at the question level

Answer (score 0):

What `EventHandler<? extends E>` means is "an event handler for `E` or some unknown subclass of `E`, so it potentially needs members of that unknown subclass, so it cannot be used with an `E`.

Probably all you need to do to fix this is to change the type of the event handler list to `CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<E>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change Observer to:

```
public static class Observers<E extends EventArgs> {
  private CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<E>> mListeners = new   CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventHandler<E>>();

  public void dispatchEvent(Object sender, E args) {
    if (mListeners != null) {
      for (EventHandler<E> listener : mListeners) {
        listener.HandleEvent(sender, args);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

E has already been defined in the class definition as extending EventArgs, it doesn't need to get redefined in each subsequent use.